# C++ : "undefined reference to WeightCalc::getHeavier(int)"

Tags: c++, class, c++11, arduino

I have the following classes detailed below: (I am programming in Arduino language which is basically C++)

Weight_Tester_main.cpp :

```
#include "Weight_Tester_main.h"
#include "weightcalc.h"

WeightCalc weight;


int PotPin = A0;
int PotVal = 0;
int ALED = 12;
int BLED = 13;


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ALED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(BLED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(btnPin, INPUT); 
    Serial.println("Setup complete. Both LEDs have been configured as outputs.                The button has been set.");
    delay(500);
}

 void loop() {
    PotVal = analogRead(PotPin);
    Serial.println(weight.getHeavier(PotVal));
}
```

Weight_Tester_main.h:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef __weight_tester_main_H__
#define __weight_tester_main_H__
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <arduino.h>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

void setup();
void loop();

 //-------------------------------------------------------------------

//===================================================================
// -> DO NOT WRITE ANYTHING BETWEEN HERE...
//      This section is reserved for automated code generation
//      This process tries to detect all user-created
//      functions in main_sketch.cpp, and inject their  
//      declarations into this file.
//      If you do not want to use this automated process,  
//      simply delete the lines below, with "&MM_DECLA" text 
//===================================================================
//---- DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- @MM_DECLA_BEG@---------------------
void loop();
void setup();
//---- DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- @MM_DECLA_END@---------------------
// -> ...AND HERE. This space is reserved for automated code generation!
//===================================================================


//-------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

weightcalc.cpp:

```
#include "weightcalc.h"

int getHeavier (int Value) {

digitalWrite(13,LOW);
digitalWrite(12,LOW);

// Ready to go boolean

boolean readytogo = true;

// Here, we know Value is the Pot's Value which our main program is going to pass to us
// So we check it for a certain value

Value = 512 ? Serial.println("Perfect!") : Serial.println("Not exact, but who cares as long as its between our range.");

if (Value > 500 && Value < 530) {

    Serial.println(" We are good to go!");
    readytogo = true;
    delay(2000);
    Serial.println("Please put the objects in each of the containers.");
    delay(20000);
}


else {

    readytogo = false;
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);


}

if (!readytogo) {

    Serial.println("Aborting......");
    return -1;
}

else {

    ;

}

int newValue = analogRead(A0);



if (newValue < 500) {

    Serial.println ("A is heavier."); 
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    return 0;

}

else if (newValue > 530) {
    Serial.println("B is heavier.");
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    return 1;

}

else {
    Serial.println("They are both about the same weight.");

    return 2;
}

}
```

weightcalc.h:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef __weightcalc_H__
#define __weightcalc_H__
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <arduino.h>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

class WeightCalc{
public:
int getHeavier(int Value);
};



//-------------------------------------------------------------------

//===================================================================
// -> DO NOT WRITE ANYTHING BETWEEN HERE...
//      This section is reserved for automated code generation
//      This process tries to detect all user-created
//      functions in main_sketch.cpp, and inject their  
//      declarations into this file.
//      If you do not want to use this automated process,  
//      simply delete the lines below, with "&MM_DECLA" text 
//===================================================================
//---- DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- @MM_DECLA_BEG@---------------------
//---- DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- @MM_DECLA_END@---------------------
// -> ...AND HERE. This space is reserved for automated code generation!
//===================================================================


//-------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I get the error you see in the title.  I am using the MariaMole IDE. I'm sorry this is mostly code but I wanted to show everything so that you can help.

Comment: You're using [reserved identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Your question is answered in the linked duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/241631) (*A common mistake is forgetting to qualify the name*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you specify WeightCalc::getHeavier(int) instead of just getHeavier(int) at the top of weightCalc.cpp? Looks like you didn't implement the declared function from the class. That one is globally defined.

Comment: Thanks! I do not know much C++ so I'll remember this!